# Implementing watchdog for docker services under sysd

Tags: docker, coreos, watchdog, systemd

I'm currently working on a docker project where, I need to implement watchdog. As Docker containers end up running as child processes of Docker daemon, they are in a cgroup different from that of the service, the sd_notify events won't be processed by sysd. For that I stumbled upon https://github.com/coreos/sdnotify-proxy.
Normally to add watchdog I'll do,

```
[Unit]
Description=My Little Daemon
Documentation=man:mylittled(8)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mylittled
WatchdogSec=30s
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitInterval=5min
StartLimitBurst=4
StartLimitAction=reboot-force
```

But how should it be implemented with `sdnotify-proxy`. I'm totally newbie to this. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage is:

```
sdnotify-proxy /path/to/unix-sock cmd ...
```

unix-sock is used to proxy the sd_notify commands from your process to systemd. To use it together with Docker, let's assume that your Docker image is called mylittled. Your service file would contain:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/sdnotify-proxy /run/mylittled-sd.sock /usr/bin/docker run \
    --volume=/run/mylittled-sd.sock:/run/mylittled-sd.sock \
    --env=NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/mylittled-sd.sock \
    mylittled
```

See https://github.com/coreos/coreos-overlay/blob/master/app-admin/flannel/files/flanneld.service for the example usage.

If you're using CoreOS: while this utility is currently included in our image (to run flannel), it is placed in /usr/libexec to not expose it for general usage. It maybe removed from the image in the future.

Comment: In my case, it's
```ExecStart=/usr/libexec/sdnotify-proxy /run/hello.sock /usr/bin/docker run \
    --volume=/run/hello.sock:/run/hello.sock \
    --env=NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/hello.sock \
    --name busybox1 pranav93/test_docker python hello.py```
Still, I'm getting env variable NOTIFY_SOCKET is not set. What can be the reason?

Comment: Solved above issue using https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Comment: I use a service mostly similar to  above one. Additionally my service uses watchdog to get hearthbeat from application running inside my container In my journal logs I see that status returned is positive for sd_notify(). This should mean that it successfully writes into socket yet my watchdog service still kills the container after timeout even my signal interval is 5 seconds and timeout is 30 seconds any idea why this might be happening ?